# iOS virtual real device with debug facility

Tags: ios, xamarin

Is there anyone know about iOS online paid service with iOS real device (Debug facility). I found few services but they only give upload project file and test. I need to Connect this to Visual studio and debug my iOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried **AWS Device Farm**? (I see, you do not like **Firebase Test Lab** as you said you do not prefer "only give upload project file and test")

Thus **AWS Device Farm** will be your best choice!

It basically **fulfills** all your needs.

- Connect to a physical iOS device ✅
- Actually use the device more than just testing apps. (ex. Swipe, Touch, Open Other iOS apps, etc..) ✅
- AWS is an industry-leading company, so quality is guaranteed. ✅

[image: Image of AWS Device Farm]

*Image of AWS Device Farm*

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

**PS**: If you need to test in Big Scale, I would personally recommend going to your local Mobile Testing Facility and consult with them. I live in Seoul and there are tons of testing facilities here.

Comment: thank you for reply. i will check it. Do they have debugging facility?

Comment: can you clarify "they" in this context?

Comment: I meant Is AWS Device Farm give debug facility. anyway thanks i will investigate about it

Comment: @AlexDemo Yes AWS has debug facility. Sure, please accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks.